# webdriver.js - Temporary elements are stealing my clicks

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm attempting to create some automated UI scripts for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 on Chrome.

In some cases, I get an exception that an element I am attempting to click on would have its click stolen by another element. The latter element, I will call a thief.

My approach is to wait until the thief is removed from the DOM using `stalenessOf` and then going about executing the rest of my script.

**Why stalenessOf is not working for me**

Sometimes, the initial error gives a css id to help track it down. However, attempts to invoke `stalenessOf` or even `findElement` on the id have failed (the thief doesn't get located before the timeout of `10000`). Perhaps because it might have been contained inside an iFrame which also disappears when the transition has completed.

**Why I can't get more information on the thief**

If I could work out the frame where the thief element is sitting in the DOM before it gets stale, that would probably give me a way forward. However, the element seems to be present for less than a second and I can't inspect the DOM quick enough before it goes stale (assuming I knew which point of the screen to inspect, which I don't).

Currently, I am hacking around it with a `Sleep(1000)` but, as you can imagine, I want to avoid this where I can.

**Summary**

In summary, I need a way to capture the details of some kind of temporary element that is part of the DOM when the page is loading so I can invoke a `stalenessOf`type method on it to wait until it is stale to move on with the rest of the script.

Comment: You can get `HTML` of your `"thief"` element from exception log. `id` value could be dynamically generated, so you just need more reliable selector to use with `stalenessOf` condition

Comment: Is the exception log the stack trace that gets spewed when the script is halted? Or is it something else. If the latter, please advise where I find it.

Comment: Or the err catch that is the second argument of the "then" promise?

Comment: I tried out using the properties on the "err" (the second param of the promise) but it contains only, stack, message and name properties. How would you get the HTML of the thief element?